# Call content areas and use variables from parent

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Ok I have an email that invokes a content area, i set a variable in my email and would like to use it in my content area, is that possible?

I would like to do something like this:

**Email**

```
<body style="background-color:#efefef;" bgcolor="#efefef">
%%[         
var @test
set @test = "Confirm your place by 30th April 2015 and save up to £2,000"
]%%         
%%=ContentAreaByName("My Contents\Main_Track_En_Partial_PH1")=%%
</body>
```

**Content Area**

```
%%=[@test]=%%
```

This gives me an error when resolving `@test`.  There is no way this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.  You just need to reference your content area variable like this:

```
%%=v(@test)=%%
```

Brackets are for personalization strings, the `v()` function is for AMPScript variables.